# How to start Hoop server in hadoop 0.23.1

Tags: hadoop

I know that hadoop 0.23.1 have included hoop as part of the system, but how do I start hoop once I installed it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after configuring the hoop-site.xml and hadoop core-site.xml, just type: bin/hoop.sh start

this link has every thing to start hoop server: http://cloudera.github.com/hoop/docs/latest/ServerSetup.html